# Trouble using openCV to load a net from ONNX (python/pytorch)

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, onnx

I'm trying to load a trained .onnx model (from a neural-style-transfer algorithm) into cv2. I've seen that there is a

```
cv.dnn.readNetFromONNX()
```

function, but there is no such function in cv2. I can't seem to import or load opencv as cv, and as such can't seem to load my model in cv2. Does anyone know a solution?

I've basically trained a model with 
https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/fast_neural_style/neural_style/neural_style.py#L122-L150
this script, and made an export of an onnx model by adding

```
torch.onnx.export(style_model, dummy_input, "chipsoft_mod.onnx", verbose=True)
```

Now I want to run the trained model trough the cv2 reader, but I fail spectacularly.

Comment: Also have faced this problem, another good reason to use/learn C++

Answer (score 1):

Update your opencv to a newer version. It should help.

```
pip install opencv-python==4.1.0.25
```